# How to serialize a non-serializable in Java?

Tags: java, serialization

How can I serialize an object that does not implement Serializable? I cannot mark it Serializable because the class is from a 3rd party library.

Comment: `class SFoo extends com.library.Foo implements Serializable {}` ?

Comment: @wchargin No. That only serializes the data of the serializable part, not of the on-serializable library part being extended.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can't serialise a class that doesn't implement `Serializable`, but you can wrap it in a class that does. To do this, you should implement `readObject` and `writeObject` on your wrapper class so you can serialise its objects in a custom way.

- First, make your non-serialisable field `transient`.
- In `writeObject`, first call `defaultWriteObject` on the stream to store all the non-transient fields, then call other methods to serialise the individual properties of your non-serialisable object.
- In `readObject`, first call `defaultReadObject` on the stream to read back all the non-transient fields, then call other methods (corresponding to the ones you added to `writeObject`) to deserialise your non-serialisable object.

I hope this makes sense. :-)

Comment: Doesn't this assume that everything that needs to get (de)serialized  in the non-serialized object is visible to the class that is wrapping it?

Comment: @whaley: Yes. Usually, what needs saving is externally-visible state anyway, so this shouldn't be a problem. (It's also no different from the constraints on your XML/JSON/YAML solution. :-P)

Comment: not sure what your bullet points 2 and 3 mean could please give a sample code (newbie in java programming)

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question, since it does not give a way to avoid adding 'implements Serializable' to any class that needs to be serialized.

Comment: @bmargulies You cannot directly serialise a class not marked Serializable. End of story. My answer allows you to write a Serializable wrapper around a non-Serializable class, that preserves its essential state.

Comment: @bmargulies I like the idea behind your edit, so I've changed the wording some to better reflect how I write. :-)

Comment: I think, even after implementing `Serializable` and adding `readObject` and `writeObject` in serialized wrapper class, wrapped class must have a no - arg constructor so that serialized class can have a no - arg constructor. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153686/no-valid-constructor-during-serialization)

Comment: Is there way to make  [this class](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html) serializable?   I don't think so because no - arg default constructor is missing in `IndexWriter` and a correct default constructor can't be added in sub class calling  [super class constructor](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#IndexWriter-org.apache.lucene.store.Directory-org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig-)

Comment: Does refelection can help this?

Answer (score 7):

Wrap the non-serializable class in a class of your own that implements `Serializable`. In your class's `writeObject` method, do whatever's necessary to serialize sufficient information on the non-serializable object so that your class's `readObject` method can reconstruct it.

Alternatively, contact the developer of the non-serializable class and tell him to fix it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kryo. It works on non serialized classes but classes needs registered aforehand.

Answer (score 0):

If your class already implements the Serializable interface (required for serializing), all you must do is to declare the field you don't want to serialize with transient:

```
    public transient String description;
```

Comment: The question was specifically about classes that *do not* implement Serializable.

Answer (score -5):

If the class is not final, you can make your own class that extends it and implements Serializable.  There are lots of other ways to serialize besides Java's built-in mechanism though.

Comment: It's worth adding that doing this won't serialize fields that are private or package-private of the super class though.

Comment: @whaley @Michael McGowan This won't serialize *any* fields of the non-serializable base class. Wrong answer, down voted.

Comment: @EJP Perhaps I should have been explicit about the need for `readObject` and `writeObject`, but those are issues any time one implements Serializable on something whose parent isn't `Object`.  The answer is really just incomplete rather than wrong, no?

Comment: this is a distinction without a difference. It is incomplete *and therefore* wrong. The part of your comment commencing 'but' is incorrect as well.