# error when writing a ResultScanner to a file in java (serialization issue)

Tags: java, serialization, hbase

When i want to write a ResultScanner object to disk, i face this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at cache1.CacheManager.getCache(CacheManager.java:112)
    at cache1.Cache1.main(Cache1.java:43)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at cache1.CacheManager.putCache(CacheManager.java:102)
    at cache1.Cache1.main(Cache1.java:41)
```

As far as i could understand,the problem is with ResultScanner (ClientScanner) not being serializable. since i don't have access to this class, how can i fix this serialization problem? or is there any other way to store this object to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will need to perform serialization by yourself, since having Serializable interface JVM cannot do it for you.

When you extend this class you can implement readObject and writeObject and serialize it by storing all state by yourself (you can read also: [How to serialize a non-serializable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163872/how-to-serialize-a-non-serializable-in-java)).

I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, but as i'm new to java i couldn't figure it out! Will you please explain it more? if possible with example.

Comment: There are thousands of articles about customizing serialization. I gave you just an idea (and keywords) and finding it on the web is quite straightforward.