# No valid constructor during serialization

Tags: java, serialization, load, runtime-error

I have a major problem during loading the extension into the program. I get an exception as there is no valid constructor.

The problem is in the line:

```
 ekstensja =  (ArrayList<Dydaktyk>) ois.readObject();
```

I get something like that:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: Dydaktyk; no valid constructor
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at Dydaktyk.wczytajEkstensje(Dydaktyk.java:81)
    at Dydaktyk.<clinit>(Dydaktyk.java:69)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.hasStaticInitializer(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeDefaultSUID(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerialVersionUID(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at Przedmiot.wczytajEkstensje(Przedmiot.java:99)
    at Przedmiot.<clinit>(Przedmiot.java:87)
    at GUI.main(GUI.java:100)
```

---

```
static {
    wczytajEkstensje(); // load Extension
}

public static void wczytajEkstensje() {// load extension
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("dydaktyk.ser");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        // here is the problem
        ekstensja =  (ArrayList<Dydaktyk>) ois.readObject();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ois != null) {
                ois.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        try {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}

public static void zapiszEkstensje() {// save extension
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("dydaktyk.ser");
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        oos.writeObject(ekstensja); // serialization
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (oos != null) {
                oos.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        try {
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the constructor of `Dydaktyk` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The class `Dydaktyk` should have an accessible (public or protected) no-args constructor so that the serialization reflection mechanism can create an instance of the class:

```
public Dydaktyk() { 
  ...
}
```

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

> During deserialization, the fields of non-serializable classes will be initialized using the public or protected no-arg constructor of the class. A no-arg constructor must be accessible to the subclass that is serializable. The fields of serializable subclasses will be restored from the stream.

Comment: Magic. Worked. Why? I would NEVER guess.

Comment: The reflection mechanism used in Serialization requires this. Also see doc update

Comment: @Yoda You're not supposed to guess. You're supposed to read the documentation. It's stated clearly in the Javadoc for the exception that was thrown.

Answer (score 3):

As specified in Oracle site about [`Serialization`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface :

> During deserialization, the fields of non-serializable classes will be
>   initialized using the public or protected no-arg constructor of the
>   class. **A no-arg constructor must be accessible to the subclass that is
>   serializable**. The fields of serializable subclasses will be restored
>   from the stream.

What I gues is that `Dydaktyk` is the subclass of some class. And you have defined the `parametric constructor` within the `superclass` and have not defined a `parameter-less constructor` within it . And the compiler isn't inserting a default constructor for that `superclass`. So , You should define a `parameter-less constructor` within your superclass also.