# Serialize hashmap with non-serializable objects

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap, javafx, components

How do i serialize a hashmap containing non-serializable objects, in my case JavaFX Components?

```
final HashMap<String, Button> mapButton = new HashMap<>();
// some for loop adding the components..
try {
     FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Resources/");
     ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
     objStream.writeObject(mapButton);
     objStream.close();
     fileOut.close();
     System.out.println("Serialized HashMap mapButtons has been stored"
                         + " in /tmp/store");
    } catch (IOException i) {
          i.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Throws:

> java.io.NotSerializableException: javafx.scene.control.Button

Comment: You can't serialize non-serializable objects. Period.

Comment: You see, the HashMap object itself is in fact serializable and only the object it contains is not. Therefore i thought it might be possible.

Comment: Yes, but how does the HashMap then serialize its items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to serialize objects than they must be `Serializable`.

Since a `javafx.scene.control.Button` is not serializable you must find another way to save the button's state somewhere else. E.g. by introducing a memento class that safes the state:

```
public class ButtonMemento implements Serializable {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       private boolean text;

       /*
        * Creates a memento that safes the given button's current state.
        */
       public ButtonMemento(Button button){
             this.text = button.getText();
            // extend to record more properties of the button
       }

       /*
        * Used to apply the current mementos state to a button
        */
       public void applyState(Button button){
           button.setText(text);
           // extend to apply more properties to the button
       }
}
```

The `ButtonMemento` class is a way to safe the state of an object that is not serializable and restore it later.

```
final HashMap<String, ButtonMemento> mapButton = new HashMap<>();

for(Button b : buttons){
    String mapKey = ...;
    mapButton.put(mapKey, new ButtonMemento(b));
}    

try {
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Resources/");
    ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
    objStream.writeObject(mapButton);
    objStream.close();
    fileOut.close();
    System.out.println("Serialized HashMap mapButtons has been stored"
                     + " in /tmp/store");
} catch (IOException i) {
      i.printStackTrace();
}
```

Maybe you can implement somthing like a `BeanMemento` that can store the properties of a bean that are serializable and therefore can be used with every object that fulfills the java bean specification.

Answer (score 1):

[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163872/how-to-serialize-a-non-serializable-in-java)

You should implement `readObject` and `writeObject` on your class so you can serialise its objects in a custom way.

- First, make your non-serialisable field `transient`.
- In `writeObject`, first call `defaultWriteObject` on the stream to store all the non-transient fields, then call other methods to serialise the individual properties of your non-serialisable object.
- In `readObject`, first call `defaultReadObject` on the stream to read back all the non-transient fields, then call other methods (corresponding to the ones you added to `writeObject`) to deserialise your non-serialisable object.

I hope this makes sense. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a serializable wrapper around Button and implement custom serialization in it. You will be saving buttons properties in writeObject, read them back and recreated Buttons in readObject