# serialize 3rd party object with no default constructor

Tags: java, serialization

I need to serialize and deserialize a 3rd party object that has no default constructor and doesn't implement Serializable interface. What are my options?

Comment: This is one option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163872/how-to-serialize-a-non-serializable-in-java

Comment: I can't make the field transient, because I need it to be part of the serialized object

Comment: That's exactly what the answer is explaining, how to make the transient field a part of the serialized object.

Comment: How can I "serialise the individual properties of your non-serialisable object"? Just copy them one by one to some other object that is serializable?

Comment: Can you extend the object and implement Serializable?

Comment: My guess would be to use the `ObjectOutputStream`'s methods.

Comment: Yes, I can extend the class.

Comment: Flagged as a duplicate question. That the answers may not provide a full solution, or you don't understand the answers, does not make the question a non-duplicate. If you have more details that sets this question apart, *update and improve your question*.